# LiveCD + truecrypt drive have write disabled

Tags: 12.04, live-cd, truecrypt

I've booted into my computer using a ubuntu 12.04 livecd, and have installed truecrypt.  I have mounted a truecrypt drive, but I can't seem to create any files/folders on the truecrypt drive.  The options are grayed out.

Anyone know why is this happening?  Even though I made sure the readonly option is disabled when mounting via truecrypt.

Apparently I am not the owner of the drive so I can't change the permissions...  I am the owner.

I've tried this on 2 different computers and both have the same issue.  However, if I mount the truecrypt drive on the original computer it was created on using a HDD installation of Ubuntu instead of a livecd, the truecrypt drive works perfectly well as expected.

So basically, using a livecd, I boot into the computer, and install truecrypt, which I guess gets installed on the computers ram. I then attach a usb storage device to the computer. The usb storage device is a fully encrypted drive. When I mount this drive using truecrypt, I can see everything in the drive, but I cannot add/edit anything in the drive.  How do write to the drive?

Comment: I do not understand the scenario you're trying to describe. What exactly are you doing, trying to achieve, what are the results you're expecting and not getting (well, that last part *is* clear; the title says that much)?

Comment: That is, truecrypt is installed on your hdd/ssd? You mounted the tc drive "into" your liveCD? *"Even though I made sure the readonly option is disabled when mounting via truecrypt."* What exactly are you trying to say here? Please be more explicit and verbose.

Comment: Using a livecd, I boot into the computer, and install truecrypt, which I guess gets installed on the computers ram.  I then attach a usb storage device to the computer.  The usb storage device is a fully encrypted drive.  When I mount this drive using truecrypt, I can see everything in the drive, but I cannot add/edit anything in the drive.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: The truecrypt drive is a file image? Who is the owner of the file?

Comment: @enzotib, It's not a file encryption, it's a whole drive encryption, usb external drive - non-system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is preliminary, but numerous options appear to be at your disposal:

- launching truecrypt as [`sudo`](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1979484.html) from terminal [`sudo truecrypt`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrueCrypt#Mount_volumes_as_a_normal_user)
- [re-booting](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1979484.html) your system
- modifying [`/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39921/device-is-mounting-as-read-only-can-copy-files-as-root) and inserting the `uid` and/or `gid` that you'd like the device to mount as, e.g. `FS_MOUNTOPTIONS="uid=1000,gid=1000"`
- again, using the [command line](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/command-line-usage), mount the [USB as removable medium](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/volume-mounted-as-removable-medium)
- *if you had* a "permission denied" error while attempting to mount, here's a solution which involves [samba](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8741/mounting-truecrypt-container-on-share)
- if your truecrypt drive were [bootable](http://www.wikihow.com/Mount-a-TrueCrypt-Volume-in-Ubuntu-12.04), you [could try](http://pzoleeblogen.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/how-to-mount-a-truecrypt-encrypted-windows-system-drive-on-linux/) `truecrypt –mount-options=system /dev/sda1 ......`
- finally, you may want to consider creating a [custom LiveCD with truecrypt pre-installed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)

Good luck!